# Windows sytem get slow when added to domain ( abc.com)

Tags: windows, windows-xp, domain, workgroup

Client OS- Windows XP

DC - Windows Server 2008 R2

Earlier all my Windows system was in workgroup. I have created domain in windows ( abc.com ) and added all the system to domain.
But in one department, where there is 10 Windows system. I have added all this system to domain. But after adding them to domain two system is working very slow.
So, i have removed that both system from domain added to default workgroup. Now the system is working fine. I don't understand why the system is working fine after removing from workgroup. Two week has been passed still the system is working fine. Note that this system is still in Workgroup.
so, what's making only this system slow when added to domain.
How to find out - the real problem.

Note:- Here slow means, whatever you open eg:- any application such as Open Office, thunderbrid etc.. even if you open Windows Explorer. it is slow.

Comment: Actually, what do you mean by slow? Slow to boot? Slow to logon? Slow to access the network? Slow to access local apps? Slow to access the internet? Stops to play a little tune before doing anything you ask it to do? All of the above?

Comment: Slow means any thing if you open. such as even if you open explorer or any application such as OpenOffice or thunderbird. It will open, but it takes times.

Comment: So you're saying that it boots normally, logs in normally and then slows down when running applications? Try to pretend that nobody here knows anything about the system you're looking at, unless you tell us, and that details like this help people give you a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

It could be something related to GPO, like proxy settings, misconfigured search suffixes, etc.

`gpresult /z` will give you detailed info about what is applying to those machines. Run in on a troublesome machine when it's joined to the domain and see if anything looks wrong.

Comment: Hi MDMarra, Thanks for your reply. Can you suggest some tools / software/ method- which will collect some data, regarding CPU, memory and HDD IOPS and that i will run when system is in workgroup and the same tool i will run when after adding the system is in domain. So that i can compare both collected data.

Comment: Usually `perfmon.exe` is the tool people use for this. It's built into Windows and can collect pretty much anything. `procmon.exe` from the [sysinternals](http://live.sysinternals.com) site might be good for this as well.

Answer (score 1):

When a computer is added to the domain it will increase the amount of network activity during start-up and also wait to contact a domain controller (this can be disabled by GPO) however all of this makes it slower for a computer on the domain compared to a computer off the domain.

1. Check the event log see if you are getting any erros at startup, services not starting or issues with group policy
2. Also check group policy run GPRESULT to see if it has the same policys as a computer that is running quickly
3. Are there hardware diffrences between the computers?
4. Check the network ports the qickest way to elimnate the hardware would be to plug a slow computer in where a fast one is and the fast one where the slow one is see if that speeds up one but slows down the other.

I know from experance that if a computer loses it connection then it will run very slow while it tries to reconnect maybe there is some connectivity issue going on but testing the above should find it if there is.